# geo_point field shows "unindexed fields cannot be searched" in kibana. Mapping is ok

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

My set-up is as follows:

I use fluentd to pass data into elasticsearch.

I use kibana to visualize.

From one of my applications I want to sent location data and visualize it using the tile map.

I declared the following mapping.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/*/_mapping/locationtypetest' -d '{

   "locationtypetest" : {
        "properties" : {
            "locationtest" : {
                "lat_lon" : true,
                "type" : "geo_point"
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Then I updated my field list via Kibana and sendt some data.

In the field list, "locationtest" shows up as "geo_point" "locationtest" .lon and .lat shows up as Number. They are marked as "indexed" but not as "analyzed"

When I search the incomming data, I see data like this:
locationtest: { "lon": 5.6769012, "lat": 57.91436209999999 }

However, it also says "Unindexed fields cannot be searched", and I am unable to use it to visualize with a tile map.

elasticsearch version: Version: 1.7.2, Build: e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z, JVM: 1.7.0_79

refresh_interval: 5s

Comment: I've just tried to replicate your issue and it worked just fine on my machine. Could you add Elasticsearch version you're using? Is your `refresh_interval` set to -1 by any chance? That could be causing this too.

Comment: es version: Version: 1.7.2, Build: e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z, JVM: 1.7.0_79  

refresh_interval: 5s